# How hackers, are hacking the websites?

Tags: php

So basically, few days ago one of my website clients, came to me, and told me that their database and website has been hacked (hackers somehow stole the md5 hashed password from database), logged in admin panel, and changed data. Well yeah, I created that page 1 and a half year ago, so I didn't know any better `hash` or salts then. Anyway, how do they hack the database? Well basically, is there any protection against that, or are they using any type of JavaScript codes, that I shouldn't allow to load, or what else?

Hope you can help me about this question, so I could create more protected websites.

This was the previous login code for that site. Added per request -

```
  public function loginUser($username, $password) {
    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
      if($username != '' && $password != '') {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'";
        $q = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($q);
        if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0) {
          if($row['level'] == 'admin') {
            $_SESSION['user_level'] = 'admin';
          }
          else {
            $_SESSION['user_level'] = 'normal';
          }
          $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
          header('location: account.php');
        } 
        else {
          header('location: error2.php');
          // Return to page and show error
        }
      }
      else {
        header('location: error1.php');
        // Show error, when people have empty fields entered
      }
    }
```

Comment: The question with the information given so far can not be specifically answered because it's too broad.

Comment: Probably via SQL injection. No way to tell at all, without code.  Also they could have just stolen a login to the admin console.

Comment: So you are asking how they hacked a random site? How is anyone supposed to know what the problem was without ANY information? What do you expect here, a list of all possible hacks? That's gonna be a loooong one :)

Comment: Well, I just would like to know, most popular ways to hack, and how to protect my client sites against them.

Comment: @VdasDorls Security can't be boiled down to a list. Go research it on your own a little and come back to ask about specific attacks. Or add information about this specific site, like the login code, and we'll tell you possible ways to hack that code.

Comment: Might be a good idea to test it against an automated penetration test service - probably SQL injection. Obviously, impossible to say without details, and the list of possible hacks is longer than can be reasonably listed here. I'd recommend getting a book - this isn't a brush-off, it's just the question really _is_ too broad.

Comment: ok, imagine you get the MD5 hash of the password, you cannot login with an MD5 hash, you need the real password. There are services that reverse MD5 hashes, and maybe the stolen hash was already known by those services.

Comment: Check that websites previous login code.

Comment: Maybe they use session fixation to access

Comment: @VdasDorls Can you also include the code that calls this login function? We need to see how you are processing the username and password to know if you were open to an injection. But probably you didn't protect username at all and `admin' AND 1 = 1;--` would have been all that it took.

Comment: public function checkIfSubmit() {
    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
      $this->loginUser($_POST['uname'], md5($_POST['password']));
    }
  }

Comment: would not using mysql_real_escape_string would be the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to say definitely without much more information, but the most likely case is that your appplication was vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/), which enabled the attacker to get the site to display the contents of the database. Another possibility is that a [directory traversal attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack) allowed them to download the DB files directly.

Since MD5 is by now completely broken (whether you use salt or not hardly matters anymore with MD5), the rest was simple.

Comment: Why md5 dosen't matter anymore? Any arguments?

Comment: @Paul Thanks to things like Amazon EC2, MD5 hashes of most lengths, 8-9-10 characters at least, [can be easily calculated and matched](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html).

Comment: @Paul MD5 can be bruteforced in relatively short time. Jeff Atwood wrote a good blog post on it with benchmarks http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html

Comment: @Paul, all this said. A salted and hashed MD5 password is still better than an unsalted one. Each step of security keeps out more people. It isn't binary. And even the best security can be breached from within.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about SQL Injection (maybe that's how they got the information in your database).

Then you should take a look at XSS.

The first thing you have to do is to validate every piece of input, EVERYTHING!

Against SQLi you should use prepared statements.

And against XSS you should encode everything!

But, hey, no worries, you could have googled all this!

Comment: I'll undownvote if you clean this up a bit and make it useful.

Comment: Ok, thanks! then you should give a useful answer.